# Cannot click the sort datatable's button

Tags: jquery, datatables

I just moved a website to another server and the datatables sorting function is not working anymore.

This is the script :

```
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
               jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    // Init dataTable
                    jQuery('#staff_table').dataTable({
                        "aaSorting":[],
                        "bSortClasses":false,
                        "asStripeClasses":['even','odd'],
                        "bSort":true,
                        "iDisplayLength": 100,
                        "aoColumnDefs": [
                            {
                                bSortable: false,
                                aTargets: [ 0 ]
                            }
                        ]
                    });
               });
            </script>
```

This is the link to the website: http://www.hgenetics.ro/category/rase-de-lapte/holstein-rase-de-lapte/tag/alb-rosu/

When i modify the "aaSorting" to :[[2, 'asc']], it dose not filter the tables.

Comment: Did you follow the right tags for your table(<tr><td><tbody><thead>..etc)

Comment: I solved the problem, but now i get DataTables warning: table id=staff_table - Requested unknown parameter '14' for row 1. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4 --> and everything is broken on the ui part :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved the error by useing

```
aoColumnDefs: [
  {
    sDefaultContent: '',
    aTargets: [ '_all' ]
  }
]
```

But my rows are overlapping when i click on the sort button. `SOLVED`

So the culprit was a `rowspan` set to `2`

I am getting closer but when i sort some colums they get 11 `<tr class="floater even" role="row">` generated just below the `thead` and i get 200 pixels of `whitespace`.